docker build fails to install package in gitlab CI/CD
I have a docker image that i use to build and show docs for my package. I want this image to rebuild every time someone make a push to the main brunch. In order to do that I created a CI/CD.
The CI/CD logs in to docker and then tries to build the image.
The login works well and the image is starting to build, but when installing the requirements The program fails and returns:

RuntimeError: can't start new thread
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

Note that I'm working with gitlab.
I tried to install any other package (not the requirements.txt file) and still got the same error.
I also tried to remove the installation (just copied some files) and it worked find.
I tried to build the image locally and it also worked (including the installation).
The docker image:
FROM *custom image*

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/docs

RUN make html

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/use/bin/python3", "-m", "http.server", "8000"]

.yml file:
echo $password | docker login -u $username -password-stdin quay.io
docker build -t mycoolimagename:latest
# taging the image 
docker push mycoolimagename:latest

